# How would I create a ListView displaying the subdirectories of a FireBase database?

Tags: firebase, flutter, listview, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to list the names of every folder in my Firebase database.

My folder structure looks something like this:

```
folder_of_users-
    user1 - 
        "name": "bob",
        "occupation": "emperor"
    user2 - 
        "name": "jennifer",
        "occupation": "surgeon"
    user3 - 
        "name": "jason"
        "occupation": "butler for emperor"
```

I want to make a ListView displaying `user1`, `user2`, and `user3`, but I'm not sure how to do that. Sorry if this is a silly question!

Edit: To be clear, I'm using FireBase's Realtime database, and I'm using Flutter. I'm trying to show the actual names of the folders, so in my example:

```
user1
user2
user3
```

Not, the actual contents of which. Again, sorry for any misconceptions, or if this is a dumb question!

Comment: check rtdb crud https://medium.com/@tattwei46/flutter-how-to-do-crud-with-firebase-rtdb-ce61e3ce53a

Comment: @griffins I want to actually display the folder names `user1`, `user2`, and `user3`. I don't think that the article you linked shows this, but I might just be blind/stupid.

Comment: check this https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-list-all-subcollections-of-a-cloud-firestore-document-17f2bb80a166

Comment: @griffins please check my edit. thank you very much for putting in the time to help me!

Comment: share a screenshot of your database